# Подключить location.search к скриптам по работе с localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть 3 js скрипта для сохранения и вывода значений `input` и `textarea` через `localStorage`.

```
    // input text, textarea
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('localstoragesave');
    function checkValidity() {};
    for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
     (function(element) {
       var id = element.getAttribute('id');
       element.value = localStorage.getItem(id);
       element.oninput = function() {
         localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
         checkValidity();
       };
     })(elements[i]);
    }


    // checkbox
    document.getElementById('8').onclick = function() {
      if(document.getElementById('8').checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('8', "true");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('8', "false");
      }
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('8') == "true") {
      document.getElementById("8").setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }

    document.getElementById('19').onclick = function() {
      if(document.getElementById('19').checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('19', "true");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('19', "false");
      }
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('19') == "true") {
      document.getElementById("19").setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }


    // radio
    var raz = document.getElementsByName('napechataj');
    for (var i = 0; i < raz.length; i++) {
      raz[i].onclick = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('napechatajRaz', this.value);
      }
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('napechatajRaz')) {
      var napechatajRaz = localStorage.getItem('napechatajRaz');
      document.querySelector('input[name="napechataj"][value="' + napechatajRaz + '"]').setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
    
    var raz = document.getElementsByName('skazhy');
    for (var i = 0; i < raz.length; i++) {
      raz[i].onclick = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('skazhyRaz', this.value);
      }
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('skazhyRaz')) {
      var skazhyRaz = localStorage.getItem('skazhyRaz');
      document.querySelector('input[name="skazhy"][value="' + skazhyRaz + '"]').setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
```

Подскажите как сделать чтобы скрипт на странице `page.php?x=1` сохранял одни данные для `input` и `textarea`, а на `page.php?x=2` другие.

Параметр `x=1` взята для примера. Имеется ввиду, что все то что в адресе после знака `?` может быть что угодно, скрипт должен обрабатывать их как разные страницы.

PS: есть подозрение что все это можно сделать через `document.location.search`, но как реализовать - понятия не имею, так как я только верстать умею.

Поможете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел, оказалось довольно простым. Может комуто еще будет полезно.

Нужно во все строки где есть `localStorage.getItem` и `localStorage.setItem` добавить  `+ location.search` после id-шника. Вот примеры:

```
element.value = localStorage.getItem(id + location.search);

localStorage.setItem(id + location.search, element.value);

localStorage.setItem('8' + location.search, "true");

if (localStorage.getItem('8' + location.search) == "true") {
  document.getElementById("8").setAttribute('checked','checked');
}

localStorage.setItem('napechatajRaz' + location.search, this.value);

var nadrukujRaz = localStorage.getItem('napechatajRaz' + location.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const val = searchParams.get("x");
```

В `searchParams` будут лежать данные из GET парамтеров со значениями в виде объекта, а через метод `get` с указанием ключа - можно достать значения этого ключа. Дальше уже использовать например `if`

Comment: Там не только x, в адресе после знака ? может быть что угодно

Comment: @Юра окей. И что?

Comment: Извините Алексей. Ваше решение наверно хорошее, но я всего лиш верстальщик и не смогу сам внедрить его в скрипты.

Comment: @Юра непонятно. Ответ на мой вопрос в комментаии какой? И что это значит всё про внедрение в скрипты?

Comment: Не умею я программировать на js и не понимаю что можно сделать с ответом

Comment: @Юра тогда не ясно что вы ожидали и ожидаете. Мы не видим через интернет ваш код, чтобы написать под него точный ответ, который можно просто выделить, скопировать и вставить ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Опять же, на мой вопрос из первого комментария не вами не дан ответ...... нну может быть что угодно в строке и что? Что это вообще значит?

Comment: По вопросу из первого комментария. Там есть такая часть ```get("x")```. Значит ли что в адресе обязательно должен быть параметр ```x```?

Comment: По поводу кода Вы правы, извините. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: "Значит ли что в адресе обязательно должен быть параметр x?"  --- нет. если его нет то в val будет просто null..... .вместо x  можно ставить что угодно